# Sourcemaps with require.js

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, source-maps, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am using grunt-contrib-requirejs to munge my files into a single file and generate a sourcemap. The sourcemap seems to be valid but is 6 lines off in the debuggers in both Chrome and Firefox. I have googled quite a bit but can't find any reasons why this would happen. Has anyone else come across a similar problem?

This is a very large project with about 200 files, i've c/p my grunt config for reference.

```
dev: {
    options: {
        baseUrl: 'assets/javascript',
        optimize: 'none',
        generateSourceMaps: true,
        mainConfigFile: 'assets/javascript/requireconfig.js',
        name: 'app',
        preserveLicenseComments: false,
        include: [
            'plugins/dropdown-toggle',
            'brand/modules/checkmate-init',
            'brand/modules/batch-handler',
            'brand/modules/dataset-editors',
            'brand/modules/recording-editors',
            'brand/modules/recording-state'
        ],
        out: 'public/assets/js/myapp.js'
    }
},
dist: {
    options: {
        baseUrl: 'assets/javascript',
        optimize: 'uglify2',
        generateSourceMaps: false,
        mainConfigFile: 'assets/javascript/requireconfig.js',
        name: 'app',
        include: [
            'plugins/dropdown-toggle',
            'brand/modules/checkmate-init',
            'brand/modules/batch-handler'
        ],
        out: 'public/assets/js/myapp.js'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to an issue with https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1054

Adding to r.js config:

```
skipPragmas:true
```

Did the trick for me.

r.js config:
https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/2.2.0/build/example.build.js#L299